# Core loss kW/cm³: UNFAMILIAR FACTOR

Tags: ferrite, loss, core

Looking at a datasheet picture, I assume this is an SI system value **Pcv core loss kW/m³**.
I haven't found this mentioned in my studying material.
What does it mean?

[image: Core loss of PC40]

Also, related question, how come in the graph in the picture it's possible for me to choose a flux density of 200mT while going up in frequency @25 kHz, 50 kHz, 100 kHz, 200 kHz, 300 kHz, 500 kHz, while in practice the Bs is decreased by core loss as frequency goes up?
Can you still get 200 mT B satauration while increasing core loss immensely at 500 kHz pushing the power output to its limit?

Comment: _”power output to its limit”_ Do you realize that your “power output” is actually core losses and that “limit” is only determined by the geometry, cooling and allowed max temperature?

Comment: It's the dissipated power output of the core.

Comment: That’s not something you would normally refer to as output power.

Answer (score 7):

If you're used to iron cores at mains frequencies, where saturation is the practical limit, or air-cores at RF frequencies, where neither saturation nor core heating occur, then ferrite cores will come as a bit of a surprise.

You have to run a ferrite core at an **appropriate** B field. There are two limits, one is saturation, which is an absolute 'never exceed' limit. The other is thermal, which is a mid or long term limit, and can be exceeded on any cycle, or for 10s or even 1000s of cycles, depending on the core thermal time constant. If you're running the core at low duty cycle, you could run at well beyond the continuous thermal limit in bursts, as long as you allowed enough time in between bursts so that the average power, leading to core temperature rise, was within limits.

In practice, unless you are running a typical ferrite core at very low frequency, in the 25 kHz region, then core heating will be the limiting factor rather than saturation.

Cycling the core from a positive flux to a negative, and back to positive, dumps a certain amount of thermal energy in the core, from the hysteresis curve. Core heating power is therefore proportional to frequency. While the saturation limit allows you to run the core at 200 mT peak at any frequency, the core heating for continuous use will be acceptable at 25 kHz, and not at 500 kHz, at which frequency you'd either have to reduce the duty cycle, or the flux.

Comment: This makes sense to a novice. Thanks.